# Back button always named as previous View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I can not find any way how to name my back button as a previos view controler. All my View Controlers are named.

This is what is happening to me: [image]
Main Menu is rooted to navigation controler and 1.view is name set by user...

Please write me if you would need more info. 
Thanks!

Comment: How do you get from "1. View" to "2. View"? Update your question with relevant details.

Comment: Using storyboard segue (show); I create 2.View in prepareForsege:`secondVC   * controller = (secondVC   *)segue.destinationViewController;` so I can pass some data. Those data are OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the navigationItem title inside of your **viewDidLoad** or **viewWillAppear**:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"MyViewTitle";
```

So when you go forward the back button will show the name of the previous view.

**Edited**

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBackButton = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"SetBackButtonTitle" 
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                    target:nil 
                                    action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:myBackButton];
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting the navigationItem title?  Is it a solution: change programmatically the name of the back button? I edited my answer, I hope it can help.

Comment: I set nav. title in vewWillAppear, I tried to set it in both ViewDidLoad and DidApperar, but it has no effect. Setting backButton programatically also does not help...

Comment: If you log self.navigationItem. what does it show up? Is it self.navigationItem valid?